# how to calculate Probability for CNN model in R?

Tags: r

I have built and trained CNN model for Image classification using `MXNET` package and I predicted Test result against model data using below snippet of code.

```
pred_test <- predict(model,test_array)
pred_test_label <- max.col(t(pred_test))-1
print(pred_test_label)
```

Along with this I wanted to know what is the probability that Test Result matching with Model data, is there any way I can check on this?

Comment: Please, be more specific about what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to estimate accuracy?

Comment: I have target variable of 10 classes(1-10). I am able to predict single class,  but would like to see output in terms of probabilities across classes against single input row. . Note: I have build CNN(convolution neural network) model using MXNET package.

Comment: What stops you from using a softmax output layer?

Comment: I tried passing "Test data set(test_array)" and "Label" values to mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput() layer, But I have got error saying
 "symbol.cc:275: RCheck failed: keys[i].length() != 0 Non Symbol parameters is only accepted via key=value style."     Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because it is unclear. Now that you have a clear question (your last comment), write it down in a comprehendible manner and make it a new post. You will have more luck receiving help this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
# Prediction of test set
preds <- predict(model, test.array)
pred.label = max.col(t(preds))-1
accuracy <- function(label, pred) {
  ypred = max.col(t(as.array(pred)))
  return(sum((as.array(label) + 1) == ypred) / length(label))
}
print(paste0("Finish prediction...accuracy=", accuracy(test.y, preds)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all the elements of pred_test column variable to get say out_sum and then divide every element of pred_text by out_sum. This way now output will sum to one and can be taken it as probability of each output node of CNN.

Alternatively, you can also get probability, if you could configure CNN model as below (note use of out_activation="softmax" below) at the time of model initialization:

```
model <- mx.mlp(train.x, train.y, hidden_node=10, out_node=5, out_activation="softmax")
```

Using this configuration, CNN model bound to give output sum to be 1 and thus can be taken each node of output as probability of each class corresponding to the each node of output.